# Select date + 3 days, not including weekends and holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've found a number of answers to the problem of doing a date-diff, in SQL, not including weekends and holidays.  My problem is that I need to do a date comparison - how many child records are there whose work date is within three days of the parent record's send date?

Most of the date-diff answers involve a calendar table, and I think if I can build a sub-select that returns the date+3, I can work out the rest. But I can't figure out how to return a date+3.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
(
    thedate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    isweekday SMALLINT NULL,
    isholiday SMALLINT NULL
);
```

And:

```
SELECT thedate AS fromdate, xxx AS todate
FROM calendar
```

What I want is for todate to be fromdate + 72 hours, not counting weekends and holidays.  Doing a COUNT(*) where isweekday and not isholiday is simple enough, but doing a DATEADD() is another matter.

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Wait... "and I think if I can build a sub-select that returns the date+3, I can work out the rest" -- Sure. Once all the work is done, you can work out the rest. :) You haven't reduced your original problem to a simpler one, your attempted reduction is equally complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Changed to include non-workdays as valid fromDates.

```
WITH rankedDates AS
    (
        SELECT 
            thedate
            , ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(
                    ORDER BY thedate
                    ) dateRank
        FROM 
            calendar c
        WHERE 
            c.isweekday = 1 
            AND 
            c.isholiday = 0
    )
SELECT 
    c1.fromdate
    , rd2.thedate todate
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT 
            c.thedate fromDate
            , 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        TOP 1 daterank
                    FROM 
                        rankedDates rd
                    WHERE
                        rd.thedate <= c.thedate
                    ORDER BY 
                        thedate DESC
                ) dateRank
        FROM 
            calendar c
    ) c1        
LEFT JOIN
    rankedDates rd2
    ON 
        c1.dateRank + 3 = rd2.dateRank
```

You could put a date rank column on the calendar table to simplify this and avoid the CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE
    calendar
    (
        TheDate DATETIME PRIMARY KEY
        , isweekday BIT NOT NULL
        , isHoliday BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        , dateRank INT NOT NULL
    );
```

Then you'd set the daterank column only where it's a non-holiday weekday.

Comment: That almost works. But because you're pulling fromDate from rankedDates, it doesn't return a value for weekends and holidays.

Comment: Oh, so you need 'todate' values for holidays and weekends, but 'fromdate' needs to be limited to non-holiday weekdays?

Comment: Yes.  Thinking about it, I could do that in the script that set the dateRank column, if I added that to the table, instead of using CFE.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, change the number in the "top" to the number of days you want to include.

```
declare @date as datetime

set @date = '5/23/13'

select
    max(_businessDates.thedate)
from (
    select 
         top 3 _Calendar.thedate 
    from calendar _Calendar
    where _Calendar.isWeekday = 1 
         and _Calendar.isholiday = 0
         and _Calendar.thedate >= @date
    order by 
         _Calendar.thedate
) as _businessDates
```

For a dynamic version that can go forward or backward a certain number of days try this:

```
declare @date as datetime
declare @DayOffset as int

set @date = '5/28/13'
set @DayOffset = -3

select
    (case when @DayOffset >= 0 then 
            max(_businessDates.thedate) 
        else 
            min(_businessDates.thedate) 
        end)
from (
    select 
         top (abs(@DayOffset) + (case when @DayOffset >= 0 then 1 else 0 end)) _Calendar.thedate
    from calendar _Calendar
    where _Calendar.isWeekday = 1
        and _Calendar.isholiday = 0
        and ( (@DayOffset >= 0 and _Calendar.thedate >= @date)
        or  (@DayOffset < 0 and _Calendar.thedate < @date) )
    order by 
         cast(_Calendar.thedate as int) * (case when @DayOffset >=0 then 1 else -1 end)
) as _businessDates
```

You can set @DayOffset to a positive or negative number.

Comment: That works, as a standalone query. But I need to use this as a subselect joined to another table, where @date is a field in that other table. And I can't, AIUI, use a field reference in the context of a subselect.

Comment: I created this as a function that I call in my select list. 

`select *, (select [dbo].[FunctionName]('myTable.thedate',3)) as offsetDate from myTable`

Comment: Added a new answer that is able to be joined to a query using dateadd.

Answer (score 0):

You just need DATEADD, unless I'm not understanding your question.

DATEADD(DAY,3,fromdate)

Edit:  I see, not counting weekends or Holidays, will update momentarily.

Update: Well looks like Jason nailed it, but on the off chance you're using SQL2012, here's the simple version:

```
SELECT todate = thedate
       fromdate = LEAD(thedate,3) OVER (ORDER BY thedate)
FROM calendar
WHERE isweekday = 1
 AND isHoliday = 0
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I first thought too, the question is worded a bit confusingly. :)

Comment: I want to add three days, not including holidays and weekends. That is, thedate + however many days it takes to have three for which isholiday is 0 and isweekday is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need it as a query with dateAdd:

```
SELECT 
     allDates.thedate fromDate
    ,min(nonWeekendHoliday.thedate) toDate
FROM (    
    SELECT 
        thedate
    FROM 
       calendar _calendar
) allDates
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        thedate
    FROM 
       calendar _calendar
    WHERE 
        _calendar.isweekday = 1 
        AND 
        _calendar.isholiday = 0 
) nonWeekendHoliday
    on dateadd(d,3,allDates.thedate) <= nonWeekendHoliday.thedate
where allDates.thedate between '5/20/13' and '5/31/13'
group by
     allDates.thedate
```